# how to stop the program from starting the next step if I wanted to display error message for erroneous entry?

Tags: python

This is how my program look like.

```
m=(input("Did the patient suffer from pain shift ? type 'y' or 'n' \n")).casefold()
if m=="y":
  M=1
elif m=="n":
  M=0
else:
  print ("error entry start over ")
```

How to get the program not to ask the next question if user entered any thing other than y or n?

I am very very beginner I am just in my 3rd day learning so I don't have enough functions dictionary to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you want to terminate the program you can use the `exit()` function.
- If you want to restart the questions from the beginning you have to use a `while` loop.

This might help you in the second case:
https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-while-loop-user-input

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer.